# Shopify Data Migration from 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I haven't found anything thing in Shopify's documentation that discusses data migration from Shopify 1.0 to 2.0. I have a lot of custom data that I have created with blocks on several pages, and don't really have to the time to migrate every page? How do we preseve the pages that we've created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify is not touching the old pages as long as we want. You can keep them as it is and start using build new pages with Shopify 2.0 - we don't need have to migrate each and every page.